# Proof check: prove that any nonzero subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$ is $\mathbb{R}^1$ itself.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $U, V$ be nonzero subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^1$ s.t. $U \cup V = \mathbb{R}^1$ , and let $k\vec u$ be some vector in $U$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$. But, $k$ is an arbitrary scalar, and $\vec u$ is an arbitrary nonzero one-dimensional vector, so by the definition of a vector space, $k\vec u \in V$. Then, $U$ and $V$ are the same, so $U \cup U = \mathbb{R}^1$, and therefore $U = \mathbb{R}^1$.

Would this work, or are there elements of rigour lacking? Thank you!

Comment: This argumentation is wrong. Firstly the argument fails if $\vec u=0$. So you should select $\vec  u$ to be a non-zero vector in $U$. Secondly, there is no reason that $k\vec u \in V$. You can state the same argument for $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^1$, and it will fail. You never use any properties of $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Comment: This proof also works if you set $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^1$. So there is some problem to it. Try to cook up a new proof, and check if it worrks in the case $U=\mathbb{R}^1\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $U \cup V = \mathbb{R}^2$. If it works in this case too - then it is wrong.

Comment: Why are you taking two spaces which union to $\mathbb R^1$? The question in the title is that if we have one subspace $U \subseteq \mathbb R^1$ that is nonzero then $U = \mathbb R^1$. Where did $V$ and this union condition come from?

Comment: @Kolja thank you for your comments! I corrected the possibility of $\vec u = 0$ But, if $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$, doesn't it have the same properties as $\mathbb{R}^1$? This is why I infer that, for an arbitrary nonzero $\vec u \in U$ and scalar $k$, $k\vec u \in V$: if I can't choose an arbitrary vector in $V$ s.t. the property of scalar multiplication holds, it would fail the scalar multiplication definition of a vector space so it couldn't be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$. But I'm not too sure

Comment: @paulblartmathcop $U, V$ are meant to span the entire $\mathbb{R}^1$. You're right that I failed here... would adding $U \cap V = \emptyset$ work? The idea is to show that any vector in $U$ is also in $V$, and since these two constitute $\mathbb{R}^1$, this would show that any one of them is in fact $\mathbb{R}^1$

Comment: Two subspaces can never intersect trivially, but my point is that I don't know what $V$ is or where you found it. Your answer should begin as the question does: "Let $U$ be a nonzero subspace of $\mathbb R^1$." If you want to introduce some other subspace, you have to say what it is.

Comment: Excuse the error, two subspaces can never intersect *in the empty set*. The notion of a trivial intersection for subspaces of a vector space is their intersection being $\{0\}$.

Comment: A subspace has the same properties of the large space - it contains $0$, and it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. I don't see why should $k\vec u$ be an element of $V$? Also, you later infer that  $U$ and $V$ are the same. This is in general not true. I think your proof needs more polishing and some additional formality.

Comment: @Kolja thank you for the comments, I'll work on it!

Comment: @paulblartmathcop thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Let $U, V$ be nonzero subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^1$ s.t. $U \cup V = \mathbb{R}^1$"

The title only speaks of a nonzero subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$. It's a priori possible that $\mathbb{R}^1$ is not a union of two subspaces, but nevertheless is has a nonzero subspace. (For example the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not the union of two subspaces, but still has nonzero subspaces.)
To start the proof correctly you have to translate the question more directly.

2. "let $k\vec u$ be some vector in $U$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$."

This is fine, but you should mention that $\vec{u}$ is some vector in $U$. The way you write this, makes it seem as though $k\vec{u}$ is some vector in $U$, which is not the intended definition, I think.

3. "But, $k$ is an arbitrary scalar, and $\vec u$ is an arbitrary nonzero one-dimensional vector, so by the definition of a vector space, $k\vec u \in V$."

This doesn't logically follow. There's nothing in the definition of a vector space that says the scalar product of an arbitrary vector in a subspace needs to belong to another subspace.

4. "Then, $U$ and $V$ are the same, so $U \cup U = \mathbb{R}^1$, and therefore $U = \mathbb{R}^1$."

This also doesn't logically follow. Noting that one vector has a scalar product that belongs to another vector space, is insufficient to conclude they are the same. You have to prove a stronger claim than that.

**Hint for the correct proof:**

Start by assuming there exists a subspace $0 \subsetneq U \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^1$. Erase $V$ entirely from the proof and from your mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!