# Proof attempt: prove that any nonzero subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$ is $\mathbb{R}^1$ itself.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification

(This is a corrected attempt after [Proof check: prove that any nonzero subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$ is $\mathbb{R}^1$ itself.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4102040/proof-check-prove-that-any-nonzero-subspace-of-mathbbr1-is-mathbbr1))

Suppose $U$ is a nonzero real vector space that is a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^1$ s.t. $0 \subset U \subset \mathbb{R}^1$, let $k \in \mathbb{R}$ be some arbitrary scalar, and choose $\vec u \in U$ and $ \vec r \in \mathbb{R}^1$ s.t. $\vec u \neq \vec r$. But, since $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$, this means $\vec u \in \mathbb{R}^1$, and by the definition of a vector space, $k\vec u \in \mathbb{R}^1$. Set $k$ s.t. $k\vec u = \vec r$.

Notice: we said of $\vec ku$ that it is both in $U$ and in $\mathbb{R}^1$ but we only said of $\vec r$ that it is in $\mathbb{R}^1$. Suppose that $\vec r$ is in $\mathbb{R}^1$ but not in $U$. Then $k\vec u \neq \vec r$, since $k\vec u$ covers a  range that $\vec r$ does not. This is a contradiction, since we set $k$ s.t. $k\vec u = \vec r$. Therefore, $\vec r$ is also in $U$.

Since we chose $\vec r$ to be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^1$, this means that any vector in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is also in $U$, but since $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$, any vector in $U$ is in $\mathbb{R}^1$.

---

I'm not to sure how to finish, however: what definition of identity could I use to finish this proof? And, otherwise, would this proof work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4102040/proof-check-prove-that-any-nonzero-subspace-of-mathbbr1-is-mathbbr1)

Comment: This is easier if you just use real numbers and not vectors.  There must be some non-zero $u \in U$, and then for *any* $x \in \mathbb{R}$ I can write $x = \frac{x}{u} u$, so $x \in U$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner that was a past attempt of mine, and have used the insight provided there to attempt this proof! Is it customary to delete a past attempt? I thought that other thread might be useful to someone else!

Comment: @Randall hm, but wouldn't I need to prove that a one-dimensional vector space has the same properties as a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Huh?  You said that $U$ was a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.  It gets its vector space structure **from** $\mathbb{R}$.  The scalar $\frac{x}{u}$ is definitely a scalar that you can scale by.

Comment: @Randall sorry, I'm new to this, but wouldn't $\mathbb{R}^1$ be a euclidean space while $\mathbb{R}$ would only be the set of real numbers?

Comment: What do you think the vector space $\mathbb{R}^1$ is?  It is the set of real numbers with ordinary addition as the vector addition and ordinary multiplication as the scaling.  Is your structure something different?

Comment: Just to confirm, you are defining this as a REAL vector space, correct?  IE the scalar field is the Real numbers?  Might be more complicated if you allow for an arbitrary field. (Not sure)

Comment: @shintuku:  I think it would be appropriate to acknowledge the previous question in this question

Comment: @Randall I understand, but (again sorry if I misunderstand, I'm new to this), it seems to me that, for a scalar $k$ and a vector $\vec x$, $k + \vec x$ is undefined unless we distinguish between the euclidean space with set of real numbers, and the real numbers. In any case, your solution is way quicker if what I'm saying is not a problem!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner will do! thank you!

Comment: @Alan should have clarified, yes! $U$ is a real vector space!

Comment: @shintuku  I think you should very carefully consider what it means for $\mathbb{R}^1$ to be a vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction between scalars and vectors in this case is (in my opinion) somewhat interesting. As pointed out in the comments, you can definitely ignore the issue and multiply/divide vectors by vectors. However, the distinction is not trivial, and I think it's worth giving a proof that distinguishes between the two.

To that end, we will use ordinary symbols for scalars, and underlined symbols for the vectors corresponding to the scalars. That is, we write $\lambda$ for a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\underline{\lambda}$ for the vector in $\mathbb{R}^1$ corresponding to $\lambda$. The vector space $\mathbb{R}^1$ is then defined to be the set
$$
\{\underline{\lambda} : \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\},
$$
together with the vector space operations of addition
$$
\underline{\lambda} + \underline{\mu} = \underline{\lambda + \mu}
$$
and scalar multiplication
$$
\lambda\cdot \underline{\mu} = \underline{\lambda\mu}.
$$
Now we begin the proof. Let $U\leq \mathbb{R}^1$ be a nonzero subspace, and let $\underline{\lambda}$ be a nonzero element of $U$. Let $\underline{\mu}$ be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^1$. Since $\underline\lambda$ is a nonzero element of $\mathbb{R}^1$, by definition $\lambda \neq 0$ as a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore there is a scalar $\mu / \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, by our definition of scalar multiplication, we have
$$
(\mu/\lambda)\cdot \underline{\lambda} = \underline{(\mu/\lambda)\lambda} = \underline{\mu}.
$$
Since $U$ is a subspace, it is closed under scalar multiplication, so $(\mu/\lambda)\cdot \underline{\lambda}$ is in $U$, and hence $\underline{\mu}\in U$.
Since $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^1$ was arbitrary, we have shown that every element of $\mathbb{R}^1$ is in $U$, and hence $U = \mathbb{R}^1$.

Comment: Thank you! This covers all the tracks and makes sure properties of $\mathbb{R}^1$ also hold in $\mathbb{R}$!

Answer (score 1):

proof:

Suppose $X$ is a nonempty subspace of $\mathbb{R^1}$.  Let $y \in \mathbb{R^1}$ be arbitrarily chosen.

Since $X$ is nonempty, $\exists x \in X$ such that $x = ay$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R^1}, a \neq 0$.  Then $ y = (\frac{1}{a})x$, where $\frac{1}{a} \in \mathbb{R^1}$.  Since linear subspaces are closed under scalar multiplication, $y \in X$.  Thus $\mathbb{R^1} \subset X$ and $X = \mathbb{R^1}$.

Comment: As good as the selected answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The subspace must have dimension  $\le1$, since it's a subspace.   And dimension  $\ge1$, since it's nontrivial.   Thus the dimension is  $1$.

But the only $n $-dimensional subspace of an $n $- dimensional space is the space itself.

Comment: This is the most intuitive proof, and as good as the select answer, thanks!